# Jquery keypress/down and animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, keypress, keydown

I am trying to make a div move left and right but my animate seems to be ignored...any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){            
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
        arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };

        switch (keyCode) {

            case arrow.left: 
                $('#block').animate({"left": "-=1px"}, "slow");
            break;

            case arrow.right: 
                $('#block').animate({"left": "+=1px"}, "slow");
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
body{
    font-family:arial, verdana;
    color:#000;
    font-size:12px;
}

#block {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AeWEc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make you `#block` as `position:absolute` or `position: relative`, that mean give some `position` properties.

```
#block {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    position:absolute
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AeWEc/1/)**

Because, `left` in animation change the `left` CSS property of an element, and `left` property works for CSS `position`.

Comment: I think position absolute is best in this case

Comment: @Sam I left it on OP's decision.

Comment: Ah brilliant, I have absolute positioned it! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Check the update [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AeWEc/2/):

```
body{
    font-family:arial, verdana;
    color:#000;
    font-size:12px;
}

#block {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```